# Optimise PHP SQL query: Sum from each year?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to build an array with the sum of all fees pr. year, as you can see in my query/code below. This is not really a great solution, since i'll have to do about 40 queries. How do built a more optimal query for this? Can't for the life of me figure this out. Should I use PHP instead with something like `while ($date< 2011-04-01) { sql; $date +1year; }` etc etc?

```
$a = "SELECT sum(field_fee_value) FROM content_type_transfer WHERE field_inorout_value = 'In' AND field_date_value BETWEEN '1996-04-01T23:00:00' AND '1997-04-01T23:00:00'";
$b = "SELECT sum(field_fee_value) FROM content_type_transfer WHERE field_inorout_value = 'In' AND field_date_value BETWEEN '1997-04-01T23:00:00' AND '1998-04-01T23:00:00'";
$c = "SELECT sum(field_fee_value) FROM content_type_transfer WHERE field_inorout_value = 'In' AND field_date_value BETWEEN '1998-04-01T23:00:00' AND '1999-04-01T23:00:00'";

$a = db_result(db_query($a));
$b = db_result(db_query($b));
$c = db_result(db_query($c));

$array = array($a, $b, $c, $d, $e);
```

Thank you very much. I'll try to elaborate if it's too hard to figure out where I'm going. Or at least trying to go.

Comment: Do your dates have to fall on the first of April?  If you can have them on Jan 1 you could do a group by on the year.  Otherwise why not make it a single query in a loop?

Comment: I would keep a running total that I would tot up at the end of each day. Managers love that sort of thing whereby they can get figures when they want that are nearly up to date.

Comment: It have to fall on the first of April, yes. No other way around it unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `GROUP BY` clause in your query to make this much more efficient. Try this:

`$results = "SELECT sum(field_fee_value), YEAR(field_date_value) as 'year' FROM content_type_transfer WHERE field_inorout_value = 'In' GROUP BY YEAR(field_date_value)";`

This query will give you the sum of the `field_free_value` for every year.

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is.. it is not just for every year, but from may to may each year. no 1st january. I tried your query but it only returned one number, not one for every year.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution:

```
SELECT sum(field_fee_value)
FROM content_type_transfer 
WHERE field_inorout_value = 'In'
GROUP BY YEAR(field_date_value)
```

Additionally you can limit query by min/ max time value

Answer (score 0):

You can consolidate the 40 queries into one

```
// replace @date to field_date_value

SELECT 
IF ( month(@date)=4 and day(@date)=1 and time(@date)>='23:00:00', 
  year(@date)+1, year(@date)) as year_distribution,
SUM(field_fee_value) 
FROM content_type_transfer 
WHERE
  field_inorout_value = 'In' AND 
  field_date_value BETWEEN '{minimum_date}' AND '{maximum_date}'
GROUP BY year_distribution;
```

expected results

```
1996 SUM(field_fee_value)
1997 SUM(field_fee_value)
...
2011 SUM(field_fee_value)
```

Comment: Looks very useful, but i'm getting this error: user warning: You have an error in your SQL syntax; 'SUM(field_fee_value) FROM content_type_transfer WHERE field_inorout_value = ' at line 4 query: SELECT IF ( month(field_date_value)=4 and day(field_date_value)=1 and time(field_date_value)>='23:00:00', year(field_date_value)+1, year(field_date_value)) as year_distribution SUM(field_fee_value) FROM content_type_transfer WHERE field_inorout_value = 'In' AND field_date_value BETWEEN 'minimum_date' AND 'maximum_date' GROUP BY year_distribution;

Comment: No errors anymore, but it only returns the result: "1996"? Can't figure it out.

Comment: what is your maximum date in the where ? and the data type of the ?

Comment: $testquery =  "SELECT IF (month(field_date_value)=4 and day(field_date_value)=1 and time(field_date_value)>='23:00:00', year(field_date_value)+1, year(field_date_value)) as year_distribution, SUM(field_fee_value) FROM content_type_transfer WHERE field_inorout_value = 'In' AND field_date_value BETWEEN '1996-04-01T23:00:00' AND '2004-04-01T23:00:00' GROUP BY year_distribution"; $testquery = db_result(db_query($testquery));
  
  echo $testquery; returns 1996.

Comment: think is caused by  T in the string.remove it and try ?

Comment: It didn't change a thing. I posted it here, so you can have a closer look. Once again, thank you very much for helping out. http://pastebin.com/c7qRh6dz

Comment: you need to loop the result as now multiple years returned

Comment: I have no idea have to create loops like that to be honest. I've tried everything I could think of :/